# Calling/Passing a data frame by another variable

Tags: r, quantmod, quantitative-finance

I am trying to extract the SPY.Close column from the data frame SPY which is created by quantmod. However, I would like to generalize this so that whatever symbol I pass initially can be used to create the close vector.

```
library(quantmod)
library(wmtsa)
library(ggplot2)
library(tseries)
library(pracma)
s <- getSymbols("SPY")
s <- as.name(s)
field <- c(paste(s,".Close",sep=""))
close <- as.vector(s[,field])
```

If I were to just type in

```
close <- as.vector(SPY[,"SPY.Close"])
```

this is successful. However they are constants and would need to be changed with every new symbol.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This line `close <- as.vector(s[,field])` didn't produce an error for you?

Comment: Sorry, yes. This was the error message. `Error in as.vector(s[, field]) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.vector': Error in s[, field] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable`

Comment: BTW, the `SPY` object is _not_ a dataframe. It's an xts object and  different rules apply for accessing its values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to pull a named object from the working envirnomnet using its character value then try `get`:

```
s <- getSymbols("SPY")
field <- c(paste(s,".Close",sep=""))
close <- get(s)[, field]


str(get(s)[, field])
An ‘xts’ object on 2007-01-03/2015-01-27 containing:
  Data: num [1:2031, 1] 141 142 141 141 141 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "SPY.Close"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "yahoo"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2015-01-28 10:06:17"
```

(The `as.name` was not needed and may have confused the matter at hand. The `s`-object was already in a form that could be used.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that `XXX.Close` will always be the fourth column in the object that `getSymbols` returns, so if your object is `X`, then `X[,4]` will give you the desired column. Of course, the single column object will still have the classes `xts` and `zoo`, which will make plotting, etc... more convenient. If you literally want a `numeric` vector of close values, you can use `X[[4]]` to drop the `xts` and `zoo` classes. In the example below I created a new environment `qm_env` to store objects in just so they wouldn't clutter up my `.GlobalEnv` - you can just ignore the `with(qm_env, ...)` part of my expressions and focus on the `...`:

```
library(quantmod)
##
qm_env <- new.env()
tickers <- c("SPY","MSFT","MMM")
##
sapply(tickers, function(x){
  getSymbols(x,env=qm_env)
})
##
with(qm_env,close <- MMM[,4])
R> with(qm_env, head( close ))
           MMM.Close
2007-01-03     78.26
2007-01-04     77.95
2007-01-05     77.42
2007-01-08     77.59
2007-01-09     77.68
2007-01-10     77.85
```

If for some reason you aren't confident that the fourth column will always be the close values, just create a function like this

```
getClose <- function(x) {
  x[,agrep("Close",names(x))]
}
```

which should do the job:

```
R> with(qm_env, head( getClose(MSFT) ))
           MSFT.Close
2007-01-03      29.86
2007-01-04      29.81
2007-01-05      29.64
2007-01-08      29.93
2007-01-09      29.96
2007-01-10      29.66
R> with(qm_env, head( getClose(SPY) ))
           SPY.Close
2007-01-03    141.37
2007-01-04    141.67
2007-01-05    140.54
2007-01-08    141.19
2007-01-09    141.07
2007-01-10    141.54
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `quantmod::getPrice`, which looks for a `"*.Close"` column by default.

```
require(quantmod)
x <- getSymbols("SPY", auto.assign=FALSE)
head(getPrice(x))
#            SPY.Close
# 2007-01-03    141.37
# 2007-01-04    141.67
# 2007-01-05    140.54
# 2007-01-08    141.19
# 2007-01-09    141.07
# 2007-01-10    141.54
```